# Generating an index from XML-files using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want  to create an index of people mentioned in a corpus of letters.

So far, I have unsuccessfully tried to implement the id-Function in XSLT. But maybe that's the wrong idea entirely.

The XML-files (ZL00004.xml and ZL00054.xml) contain persName elements that use the key-attribute to reference persons in the person.xml file.

ZL00004.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="ZL00004">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>450</title>
            </titleStmt>
        </fileDesc>
        <profileDesc>
            <correspDesc>
                <correspAction type="sent">
                    <persName key="ZP00002">Hugo Grotius</persName>
                </correspAction>
                <correspAction type="received">
                    <persName key="ZP00001">Justus Scaliger</persName>
                </correspAction>
            </correspDesc>
        </profileDesc>
    </teiHeader>
    <text type='letter' xml:lang="en">
    <body>
        <div>
            <opener>
                <salute>My dear <persName key="ZP00001">Justus</persName>,</salute>
            </opener>
            <p>Some text that mentions <persName key="ZP00003">Isaac </persName></p>
            <closer>Best regards, 
                <lb></lb>
                <signed><persName key="ZP00002">Hugo</persName></signed>
            </closer>
        </div>
    </body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

ZL00054.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="ZL00054">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>800</title>
            </titleStmt>
        </fileDesc>
        <profileDesc>
            <correspDesc>
                <correspAction type="sent">
                    <persName key="ZP00001">Justus Scaliger</persName>
                </correspAction>
                <correspAction type="received">
                    <persName key="ZP00002">Hugo Grotius</persName>
                </correspAction>
            </correspDesc>
        </profileDesc>
    </teiHeader>
    <text type='letter' xml:lang="en">
        <body>
            <div>
                <opener>
                    <salute>My dear <persName key="ZP00002">Hugo</persName>,</salute>
                </opener>
                <p>Some text that mentions <persName key="ZP00003">Isaac</persName> and <persName key="ZP00002">Hugo</persName>.</p>
                <closer>Best regards, 
                    <lb></lb>
                    <signed><persName key="ZP00001">Justus</persName></signed>
                </closer>
            </div>
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

persons.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Persons>
<person xml:id="ZP00001">
    <persName><forename>Joseph Justus</forename><surname>Scaliger</surname></persName>
</person>

<person xml:id="ZP00002">
    <persName><forename>Hugo</forename><surname>Grotius</surname></persName>
</person>

    <person xml:id="ZP00003">
        <persName><forename>Isaac</forename><surname>Casaubon</surname></persName>
    </person>
</Persons>
```

The goal is to create an index with entries for every person that refers to the number of the respective letters (title-element). The persons are ordered alphabetically. The index refers to each according to their function. Persons mentioned in letters by Grotius are grouped in "mentHG" – persons mentioned by other senders are grouped in "mentO":

- Casaubon is mentioned in the letter no. 450 by Grotius - which is indicated by "mentHG". Since only Scaliger mentions him in letter no. 800, this is emphasized.
- Grotius is indicated as the sender of letter no. 450 and the recipient of no. 800. His being mentioned in no. 800 is not emphasized as the letter is by Scaliger.
- Scaliger is indicated as the sender of letter no. 800 and the recipient of no. 450.

The output should look something like this:

**Casaubon, Isaac**

- *mentHG* 450, (plus more letters)
- *mentO* 800, (plus more letters)

**Grotius, Hugo**

- *Sender* 450, (plus more letters)
- *Adressee* 800, (plus more letters)
- *mentO* 800, (plus more letters)

**Scaliger, Justus**

- *Adressee* 450, (plus more letters)
- *Sender* 800, (plus more letters)

This is as far as I got with my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each
      select="document(/library/document/@filename)/tei:TEI">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tei:TEI">

    <xsl:for-each select="Persons/person">
      <xsl:text>&#xA; </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      <xsl:text> (ID </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@xml:id"/>
      <xsl:text>) is found in these letters:&#xA;</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:value-of select="//@xml:id[idref(@xml:id)]" 
        separator="&#xA;"/>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text> 
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck in your approach to solve this? (show us the XSLT code)

Comment: I suspect you want to use the `key()` function, not the `id()` function. Note that both behave differently in XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.

Comment: We can't tell you where your code is wrong without seeing your code. Using key() is generally more reliable than using id(). (Some XML parsers don't report which attributes are marked as IDs, and in the case of the xml:id attribute, some people are still using XSLT processors that were developed before the xml:id spec was even published.)

Comment: Where do you start from, the `persons.xml` to find `person` elements and then their references in the collection of letters, or the letters to find `persName` elements and look up their complete names in the `persons.xml`?

Comment: I added the last version of my XSL-file.

Comment: I have tried to establish some key based cross-references in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWY/2, I have not yet managed to understand when references in the body should not be used in the "mentioned" categories. Is that for that particular author "Scaliger" and for any `signed` reference?

Comment: The index is centered around Grotius. For this reason, the persons mentioned in his letters are indicated by "mentHG". My feeling was that this condition could be extracted from the type attribute in the correspAction-element.

Comment: That is a very impressive XSL-file and exactly what I was trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion using keys and XSLT 2/3 from the link in the comment, only adapted to not have the letters inlined but loading them as you did in your sample using the document function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="letters" select="document(/library/document/@filename)"/>

  <xsl:key name="sender" 
    match="tei:TEI" 
    use="tei:teiHeader/tei:profileDesc/tei:correspDesc/tei:correspAction[@type = 'sent']/tei:persName/@key"/>

  <xsl:key name="adressee" 
    match="tei:TEI" 
    use="tei:teiHeader/tei:profileDesc/tei:correspDesc/tei:correspAction[@type = 'received']/tei:persName/@key"/>

  <xsl:key name="letter-ref" match="tei:TEI" use="tei:text//tei:persName/@key"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="grotius-letters" select="key('sender', 'ZP00002', $letters)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="others-letters" select="$letters/tei:TEI except $grotius-letters"/>

  <xsl:template match="Persons">
      <xsl:where-populated>
          <ol>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="person">
                  <xsl:sort select="persName/surname"/>
                  <xsl:sort select="persName/forename"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
          </ol>
      </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person">
      <li>
          <b>{persName/surname}, {persName/forename}</b>
          <xsl:variable name="letters-sent" select="key('sender', @xml:id, $letters)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="letters-received" select="key('adressee', @xml:id, $letters)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="mentioned-grotius" select="key('letter-ref', @xml:id, $grotius-letters)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="mentioned-others" select="key('letter-ref', @xml:id, $others-letters)"/>
          <xsl:where-populated>
              <ul>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$letters-sent" mode="ref-item">
                      <xsl:with-param name="ref-type" select="'Sender'"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$letters-received" mode="ref-item">
                      <xsl:with-param name="ref-type" select="'Adressee'"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$mentioned-grotius" mode="ref-item">
                      <xsl:with-param name="ref-type" select="'mentHG'"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$mentioned-others" mode="ref-item">
                      <xsl:with-param name="ref-type" select="'mentO'"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </ul>
          </xsl:where-populated>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tei:TEI" mode="ref-item">
      <xsl:param name="ref-type"/>
      <li><em>{$ref-type}</em> {tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title}</li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWY/2

It doesn't have quite the output you have shown in your question but as you said in your comment it is "exactly what I was trying to achieve" I hope you can adapt it to exclude some references if needed.

The code uses XSLT 3 as available with Saxon 9.8 and later but of course the XSLT 3 only features used, like text value templates and the `xsl:mode` declaration, could be replaced easily in XSLT 2 by the use of `xsl:value-of` and a spelled out template for the identity transformation.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I believe I can tweak it from here.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still using XSLT 2 and I fail to convert the XSLT 3 features back to the older version. It's not exactly intuitive.

Comment: Any "text value template" in the form of e.g. `{$ref-type}` becomes e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$ref-type"/>`. Drop the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` and spell it out in a template `<xsl:template match="@* | node()"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: As for the use of `<xsl:where-populated>`, I would suggest to drop it, it is a nice feature in XSLT 3 allowing to easily and elegantly ensure  that in the generated HTML list containers like `ul` or `ol` don't end up empty in the case there is no content as technically then you had invalid HTML. But browsers won't complain about `ul`s or `ol`s without `li`s inside. If you still have problems, consider raising each as a separate question.